# Jquery get text value of some selector using index in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following code with jQuery:

```
var ths = $(".timetable__table th");
var th;

    for (var i = 0; i < ths.size(); i++) {
      th  = ths.get(i).text();
      console.log(th);
    }
```

When I try to execute this code I get the following exception: `TypeError: ths.get(...).text is not a function`. I don't understand why it occurs, I just need to get the text value of a tag. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this, Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function at this context to traverse over a collection of jquery object.

```
$(".timetable__table th").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).text());
});
```

`.get(index)` would return a javascript object and that does not contains a function called `.text()`

**Note:** Keep in mind that `.size()` has been deprecated from the version 1.8 use `.length` instead

Answer (score 1):

because [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the dom element not a jQuery object(the `.text()` is a method of jQuery wrapper object) use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) which will return a jQuery object

```
var ths = $(".timetable__table th");
var th;

for (var i = 0; i < ths.size(); i++) {
    th = ths.eq(i).text();
    console.log(th);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the underlying DOM element(s), which don't have a text()  method. Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead.

Looks like you didn't decide if you want to use the DOM or jQuery. Your code can be simplified to something like:

```
$(".timetable__table th").each(function(index, el) {
    console.log($(el).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate array like `th[i]` :

```
var ths = $(".timetable__table th");
var th;

    for (var i = 0; i < ths.size(); i++) {
      th  = ths[i].text();
      console.log(th);
    }
```

But easiest way is below where you can skip for loop and simply use `.each` :

```
$(".timetable__table th").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```